# At what point does a chazzan take three steps back after chazaras hashatz?

Tags: halacha, minhag, shemoneh-esrei, chazzan-prayer-leader

Just a question I've never been able to find a concrete answer to. At what point does a chazzan take his three steps back at the end of chazaras hashatz? Would it be while/after saying "Yihyu l'ratzon"? Or does he keep his feet together until the end of Kaddish Shalem (for example, on Shabbos shacharis/mussaf)?

What about when there's something in between the end of chazaras hashatz and kaddish, like avinu malkeinu (for example, on rosh hashana shacharis)?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! I hope you'll look around and find other material of interest, perhaps starting with our 100+ other [tag:chazzan-prayer-leader] questions. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. Finally, please [edit your profile](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/7086) to give yourself a name more distinctive than user7086!

Answer (score 6):

In [Shulchan Aruch siman 123 siff 5](//he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%92#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.94) the [Mechaber](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1693) tells us the Sha'tz does not need to take 3 steps back after his repetition aloud of the Shmoneh Esrei. The [Mishna Berurah 18](//he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%92) explains this is because he relies on the three steps he takes back after Uvah Litzion, and even though there might be Krias Hatorah and Hallel and Avinu Malkeinu, it is not a hefsek (disconnect) due to the fact that all of these come only because of the Tefila, and the Kadesh comes for that.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So after chazaras hashatz the chazan does not need to keep his feet together after saying "yihyu l'ratzon" because he will be taking three steps back at the end of Kaddish?

Comment: I also heard once this answer. But what happens if the Sha'tz for second part of the prayer (Ashrei and after that) is not the same person?

Comment: @jutky http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66455