# Taking three steps back after every Kaddish

Tags: tefilla, minhag, kaddish, bowing-kneeling

The reasons for taking three steps back and bowing in different directions after one's personal Shemoneh Esreh and for the Chazan towards the end of Kaddish Tiskabbel are provided by poskim (see sources cited in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15755/3403) and in [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45685/3403)).

What I don't understand however, is the why these conducts are practiced during Kaddish Yasom and Kaddish D'rabbanan (as well as Kaddish at a graveside/siyum), as we are not "taking leave" of God after these Kaddishim, nor do the Kaddishim correspond with the Tamid offerings?

Comment: found a possible answer here, http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?cat=378&id=28388&q=#12b though not particularly satisfying nor sourced

Comment: I think what you find confusing is that people sometimes say a kaddish after a short study session (like shir shel yom), take leave, and then immediately begin a new short study session (like barchi nafshi or ledavid or alenu), and then say kaddish and take leave again. The apparently silly part here of taking leave twice is indeed silly and would be rectified by not cutting your study session short when you expect to continue momentarily.